# Change the colour of the md-focused checkbox in angular material design

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material

I am using Angular Material and I have used md-checkboxes throughout however when I have a checkbox checked and focused it gives me a strange pink circular shadow around the checkbox (I just want to be able to change the colour)

```
<md-checkbox class="gray md-default-theme md-checked" checked="checked">
```

// When this is checked and in focus it adds the class 'md-focused' & gives this a faint pink circle around the checkbox

```
<md-checkbox class="gray md-default-theme md-checked md-focused" checked="checked">
```

Can anyone explain how I alter this to change the colour via css?

Comment: Dont see such behaviuor in their demo page. (Assuming you are using the same). https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override `.md-focused .md-container:before` because the style is added to a pseudo-element... ([PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/M0qsm9chkG3VPoUInaz7?p=preview))

- **To override all checkboxes focus:**

  ```
  md-checkbox.md-focused .md-container:before {
      background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  ```
- **To override just certain checkboxes:**

  HTML

  ```
  <md-checkbox class="md-checkbox-no-focused">
      Checkbox without focus
  </md-checkbox>
  ```

  CSS

  ```
  .md-checkbox-no-focused .md-container:before {
      background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  ```